# How to style elements that don't contain a certain element

Tags: css, parent-child

I have a menu system that contains both text, and images. My images are slightly larger ( in height ) than the text is and would like to add a little more margin space to the  elements that don't contain an image inside it. How would I go about doing that? My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id = "menu2">
  <div>
    <a href = "index.php">
      <img src = "images/home.png" alt = "Home" title = "Home"/>
    </a>
    <a href = "#">
      Menu_Item_1
    </a>
    <a href = "#">
      Menu_Item_2
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my case, I would like to style (using css/css3) the  elements that don't have an image child.

Comment: if you can add class to elements that contain image (e.g. class="have-img"), then you can use :not pseudo selector like this:
a:not(.have-img)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `line-height` to your links:

```
line-height: 50px;
```

Where `50px` depends on your images height.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9LJm/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "menu2">
<div>
<a href = "index.php">
  <img src = "images/home.png" alt = "Home" title = "Home"/>
</a>
<a href = "#" class="ses">
  Menu_Item_1
</a>
<a href = "#" class="ses">
  Menu_Item_2
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<style>
#menu2 a .ses{
color:#f2f2f2;// whatever you want..
}
</style>
```